# Force fsck safe?

Tags: fsck

My ubuntu system just froze, and I was forced to run the REIUSB commands. Now, in windows, you can run chdsk. I've read about "touch /forcefsck", but I have also read that's is dangerous to check a mounted filesystem.

Will "touch /forcefsck" check the disks mounted? Is "touch /forcefsck" safe? Will it automatically fix the errors? Where will my corrupt file go?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`touch /forcefsck` simply creates a file `/forcefsck`. This file will cause the system to run `fsck` on the next reboot before the filesystem is mounted. Its similar to when you try to run `chkdsk` in Windows and it says it can't but it will do it on the next reboot.

So its pretty safe and with any luck it will fix your problem.

Comment: Will it automaticly fix the errors?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. It is safe enough, and some distros will routinely run this every 30 days.

The generally preferred method is to boot a live distro and check the drive as a non-system device, partition by partition if need be. You can run `e2fsck -c -c` to check for bad blocks, it will take a while. Note that for LVM groups some special handling is required. (check from /dev/mapper/...). The most recent versions of GParted and the like do this fairly handily.