# Performance issues after power outage

Tags: 20.04, performance

Since a power outage my Ubuntu 20.04 PC is slow. I cannot run kdenlive projects that I could before. Kdenlive renders stutter when played. Copy paste fails with larger files.

I have found no errors with:

- `fsck` on the system disc
- `memtest86` for two nights

Are there any more steps I might take or must I reinstall Ubuntu?

EDITED TO ADD

Following Pablo Bianchi's suggestions:

- `Forcefsck` doesn't work for me but I already ran fsck from LiveUSB and the system disc shows no errors
- `journalctl -p err` shows no error
- I saw nothing untoward with `htop` although I am not confident I used it correctly
- I reset my bios

Comment: Seems a hardware issue. Try to [force a check](https://askubuntu.com/a/476314/349837). You may also want to: see system logs (`journalctl -p err`), process and I/O throughput with `htop`, boot the hdd on another hardware, check/reset BIOS setup, try recovery boot

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated my post accordingly.